# Can a single socket handle multiple concurrent requests?

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2

**Edit: My application is multi-threaded**

Imagine I have a server,

```cpp
int main()
{
   resolveAddrandPort(hostname, port); // Custom function
   
   SOCKET listening_socket = socket(/* args... */);   // Creates a socket.
   bind(listening_socket, /* args... */);             // Binds the socket to the address and port provided above.

   listen(listening_socket, default_backlog);         // Places the socket in a mode where it can accept any requests.

   add_handlers(10); // Custom function that adds 10 handlers which each run on different threads and can handle requests concurrently (using the same socket[=listening_socket]).

   while(is_recieving_requests)
   {
       SOCKET client_socket = accept(listening_socket, /* args... */);
       handle_request( // Custom function
            find_available_handler(), // Custom function that finds among the 10 handlers which of them is currently free and not handling any requests to handle this request.
            client_socket
       ); 

       clean_up(); // Custom function that cleans up after finishing with the request.
   }

   server_clean_up(); // Cleans up after the server.
}
```

I am using winsock to create the server,

In the documentation about [`listen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen) says that you can provide a backlog determining how many requests can be pending.

Now this might be dumb, but I am assuming that a single socket **cannot** concurrently handle multiple request. If so, I think that I have to create multiple `listening_socket`s to be able to handle it concurrently.

Please correct me if I am wrong and I thank you for your patience.

Comment: You can handle multiple requests with a single socket. Think about UDP as an example. You just listen on one socket from any random request.

Comment: Also in TCP you use a single listen socket to accept incoming connections, which then you can assign a separate socket to distinguish each connection.

Comment: I'm also unsure about this `single socket cannot concurrently handle multiple request` What do you mean by concurrently? Like simultaneously? In a single threaded application that wouldn't be possible anyway.

Comment: @Irelia My application is multi-threaded. And yes simultaneously

Comment: Why is it multithreaded?

Comment: @Irelia Server IO would be more efficient

Comment: That's not necessarily true. You can run very efficient servers in a single thread. Most people who use multithreaded servers don't really understand their purpose of why they're doing it.

Comment: I mean you can, but it is way easier to just delegate that work to different threads. And multi-threading was made for situations like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but I'll try to summarize. You can have a single listen socket to accept requests from incoming connections or messages (regarding UDP).

> single socket cannot concurrently handle multiple request

The concurrently is what's throwing me off. The backlog implies you can have an x maximum number of requests pending until you either accept or drop them, then new requests will be allowed.

In TCP, a single listen socket will be used to accept requests from connections. You can then distinguish each connection with its own socket.

In UDP a single listen socket can be used to accept requests which are defined by their remote address. You can also send to many different connections using that remote address with a single socket.

I think the ambiguity in your question lies about whether you can read requests from many sockets simultaneously in a single thread. In typical blocking I/O you can only read from one socket at a time. Which is why Non blocking sockets exist. This can let you loop through each socket and check if there's pending data. In which case the data can be retrieved.

If you're thinking about running a thread per socket so you can read a request from each one (which many beginners to networking do because they learnt it from somewhere). And judging by your code it appears to be what you're doing. THIS IS A TERRIBLE IDEA! It might be an "OK" solution for ephemeral sockets (single HTTP requests) but not for long term connections. But I would not even use a thread per socket even for a single request. This can lead to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple listening sockets. One works just fine.

When a connection request comes, a new connection is created, `accept` returns a new socket made specially for that connection, and you continue to serve that connection from that socket. Meanwhile the listening socket is ready to accept a new connection.

You cannot have many connection requests coming at the same time because a single physical connection (Ethernet or whatever) transmits one packet at a time. The backlog thing is for when requests are coming faster than you can `accept` them (still one at a time). In a multithreaded server this is basically a non-issue. `accept` is pretty much instant, you send the resulting socket to a worker thread to serve, and then the listening thread is ready to `accept` again.

This is all about TCP. UDP works a bit differently, there are no connections, just messages.

Comment: If a connection if kept alive, and `EPOLLONESHOT` is set, can multiple HTTP requests be waiting to be read on the socket? I am building a simple multi-threaded server with a queue of connection FDs. Once an event triggers `epoll_wait`, I queue the FD and handle it on another thread, rearming the FD after reading/parsing the data from the socket. I'm wondering if, when the data is being read, it's possible that more than one HTTP requests gets shoved into the same buffer.

Comment: @calvinsomething If you have a question, gently press the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple listening sockets, and in fact you *can't* have multiple TCP listening sockets.

You have a single listening socket.  That socket is used to accept connections, and each of those connections is assigned its own socket.

You can have one thread that listens for new connections, then when it gets one it can pass the accepted socket to either a new thread or an existing thread in a pool.  That way, you have one thread that just listens for new connections, and a number of other threads that each handle an active connection.  This will have limitations, for example if you have more threads than CPU cores then some will be waiting on others, but it will work.